# Updating model on kendo grid

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

So I have the below kendo grid on my view. At certain points an ajax call will update the Model.Id used in the model. The problem is when the Model.Id is updated the model on the grid isn't. Is there any way to update this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OfferStatementVm>().Name("gridStatementList")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Statement).Title("STATEMENT");
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
            command.Custom("custom-delete").Click("statementList_onDelete").Text("DELETE");
        }).Title("Actions").Width(165);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Statement"))
    .NoRecords("No Statements Found")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.OfferId).DefaultValue(Model.Id);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetStatementList", "OffersCreateOrUpdate", new { Area = "Offers"})
            .Data("offerApp.getStatementListSearch"))
        .Sort(x => x.Add("Id"))

        .Create(create => create.Action("InsertStatement", "OffersCreateOrUpdate", new { Area = "Offers" })
            .Data("offerApp.getAntiForgeryToken('#offersCreateOrUpdateForm')"))

        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateStatement", "OffersCreateOrUpdate", new { Area = "Offers" })
            .Data("offerApp.getAntiForgeryToken('#offersCreateOrUpdateForm')"))

        .Events(events => {
            events.Error("offerApp.statementList_onError");
            events.Sync("offerApp.refreshStatementList");
        }))
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("offerApp.statementList_onDataBound")))
```

Cheers,

Z

Comment: What's your update controller action look like? You should be returning the updated viewmodel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this by moving the grid into a partial view and rendering it once I had a valid Model.Id.